# Instead of marking specific Todo as done, function marks all the Todos as done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to mark a targeted todo as done, but instead when i press and todo as done, all the list are marked done which im trying to figure it out why, can anyone explain to me what im doing wrong ? I'm still a beginner and try to understand such behaviors.

The function handleDoneTask was suppose to run for each todo and when i press done it should be mark that specific todo in a list as done task

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [doneTask, setDoneTast] = useState(false);

  const addTodos = (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  };

  const handleDoneTask = (id) => {
    const DoneArray = [...todos];
    DoneArray.map((_, key) => {
      if (id === key) {
        setDoneTast(true);
      }
    });
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <div className="arrange" key={key}>
            <li className={doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}>{todo}</li>
            <a onClick={() => handleDoneTask(key)}>Done</a>
            <a onClick={() => handleDelete(key)}>Cancel</a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//css
.doneTask {
   text-decoration: line-through!important;

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the code for `setTodos` in your question?

Comment: This is all my code Sir, i don't know if i answered your question ?

Comment: How about the `setDoneTast` function?  Do you have code for that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Those are the setters returned by `useState`.

Comment: setDoneTask ( i wrote as tast ) , is a hook im using which once it is true im rendering conditionally the .doneTask class in css

Comment: I find the typo `setDoneTast` distracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all your tasks depend on one state `doneTask` which will be `true/false` for all tasks.

A solution you split the task element in it's own component and move the state to the task component.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.scss";

function Task({ todo, handleDelete, key }) {
  
  const [doneTask, setDoneTast] = useState(false);

  const handleDoneTask = (id) => {
        setDoneTast(true);
  };
  return <div className="arrange">
            <li className={doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}>{todo}</li>
            <a onClick={() => handleDoneTask(key)}>Done</a>
            <a onClick={() => handleDelete(key)}>Cancel</a>
          </div>
}

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <Task todo={todo} key={key} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Before i split them my friend, so the problem is just by splitting into two components ? if so shouldnt be the same behavior in this case, or separating it into 2 component will fix it ?

Comment: You need to split into a separate component, so each `task` has its own `doneTask` state, but in your code, all tasks share the same `doneTask` state.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate component to represent a `Todo` which maintains its own state.

Note that `<div>` is not valid as a direct child of an unordered list. You can, however, put it inside a list item.

```
function Todo({ name, onCancel }) {
  const [doneTask, setDoneTask] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li className="arrange">
      <span className={doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}>{name}</span>
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => setDoneTask(true)}>Done</a>{" "}
        <a onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addTodos = (e) => {
    if (val === "") return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
  };
  const handleDelete = (idx) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, i) => i !== idx));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, i) => (
          <Todo name={todo} onCancel={() => handleDelete(i)} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain an array of objects each with their own `id`, `text`, and `done` status you'll find it much easier to maintain your state. Adding the `id` to each list item as a [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) means that you can manipulate the todo objects in state more easily.

In addition if you split up your code into separate components you can have your `Form` component responsible for the state of the input element, and just have `Todo` as a dumb component that just accepts and displays data.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // One state for the todos (an array of objects)
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  // When a new todo is added we add the text in
  // an object along with a unique id, and a done status
  function handleAdd(text) {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      { id: todos.length + 1, text, done: false }
    ]);
  }

  // When a delete button is clicked find the closest
  // list item it's within, then grab the id from the dataset,
  // and use that id to filter out the desired object
  function handleDelete(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest('li');
    const { dataset: { id } } = item;
    const filtered = todos.filter(todo => {
      return todo.id !== Number(id);
    });
    setTodos(filtered);
  }

  // Similarly to "delete" when a "done" button
  // is clicked find the closest list item it's within,
  // then grab the id from the dataset, and use that id
  // to change the done status of the desired object
  function handleDone(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest('li');
    const { dataset: { id } } = item;
    const mapped = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === Number(id)) {
        return { ...todo, done: true };
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(mapped);
  };

  // Have separate components for the Form, the
  // list of Todos (in case you want to style that
  // differently), and each Todo, passing down the
  // relevant handlers to each
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form handleAdd={handleAdd} />
      <TodoList>
        {todos.map(todo => {
          return (
            <Todo
              key={todo.id}
              data={todo}
              handleDone={handleDone}
              handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
          );
        })}
      </TodoList>
    </div>
  );
}

// Form handles its own input state.
// When the add button is clicked it calls the
// handleAdd function passed to it in props
function Form({ handleAdd }) {
  
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  function handleInput(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleButton(e) {
    handleAdd(text);
    setText('');
  }
  
  return (
    <section className="form">
      <input
        onChange={handleInput}
        value={text}
        type="text"
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleButton}
      >Add
      </button>
    </section>
  );

}

// TodoList displays a list of todos
function TodoList({ children }) {
  return (
    <ul className="todolist">
      {children}
    </ul>
  );
}

// Each todo is handed a set of data (id, text, done status),
// and a couple of handlers. Depending on the status of done
// we can strike out the todo in the HTML
function Todo(props) {
  
  const {
    data: { id, text, done },
    handleDone,
    handleDelete
  } = props;
  
  const cn = ['text', done && 'strike'].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <li data-id={id}>
      <span className={cn}>{text}</span>
      <section className="buttons">
        <button
          className="done"
          type="button"
          onClick={handleDone}
        >Done</button>
        <button
          className="delete"
          type="button"
          onClick={handleDelete}
        >Delete
        </button>
      </section>
    </li>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.done:hover, .delete:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.delete { background-color: salmon; }
.done { margin: 0 0.5em; background-color: lightgreen; }
.strike { text-decoration: line-through; }
.todolist { list-style: none; border: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 1em; width: 80%; }
.todolist li { display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; padding: 0.25em;}
.todolist li:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 0.25em; }
.todolist li .buttons { margin-left: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```